# How to insert an item in-between an array using traditional forloop based on criteria?

Tags: javascript

How to insert an item in-between an array using traditional forloop based on criteria?

```
const itemToInsert = {id: '23r', distance: 100}

const items = [
    {id: 'rtr', distance: 200},
    {id: 'ruy', distance: 120},
    {id: 'let', distance: 90},
    {id: 'rll', distance: 170},
    {id: 'brr', distance: 210},
]
```

what I've tried:

```
for(let i=0, temp, item; i<items.length; i++) {
    item = items[i]

    if(item.distance < itemToInsert.distance) {
        temp = item
        items[i] = itemToInsert
        items.concat([temp])
    }
}
```

So the idea here is to insert in-between an array based on param distance.

Seems like thought mine is working fine. I see it's not inserting properly.

Comment: You're probably looking for `Array.splice()`.

Comment: I don't wana use splice. for performance I need it in traditional loop

Comment: @mex you kinda have to use splice for this; there's no way to insert between 2 elements without either creating a new array OR splice; creating a copy of the array would be less performant

Comment: There can sometimes be weird issues when adding/removing items in an array as you are looping over it.  Maybe you just need to break out of the loop after you find the spot you want?

Comment: Also, this seems like a premature micro-optimization; that's typically advised against

Comment: Yes. It is behaving strange & not as expected. though insertion occurs in-between... it is not working as expected

Comment: Can someone  suggest a better way??

Comment: @mex `Array.concat()` returns a new array, it doesn't modify the array in-place.

Comment: I also want it to be more performant

Comment: @mex - to avoid odd behavior, I'd build up a new array while looping through the old, inserting what I need when the criteria is met

Comment: You talk about optimization, but what length could your arrays have? 1k+, 10k+? If it's less than this, I really think you don't need to worry with this kind of micro-optimization. Or use `splice` or go with Derek's suggestion.

Comment: @mex Also, using `concat()` to add an array of one element can _possibly_ be simplified to `items.push(temp)`.

Comment: Just a small nit-pick, but I'd suggest adding semicolons to the end of your lines.

Comment: Can someone suggest some snippets.

Answer (score 1):

### For loop sample

Based on your original post, this is a simple example of how I'd build the new array with both post and pre insertion based on criteria:

```js
const data = ['derek', 'was', 'here', 'and', 'there'];
const newArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  const datum = data[i];
  
  if (datum === 'here') {
    newArr.push('not');
  }
  
  newArr.push(datum);
  
  if (datum === 'and') {
    newArr.push('or');
  }
}

console.log(newArr);
```

#### Sort sample

If array order doesn't matter, I'd suggest using a sort. In this sample, I'm inserting into the array, and then sorting the array desc based on distance

```js
const itemToInsert = {id: '23r', distance: 100}

const items = [
    {id: 'rtr', distance: 200},
    {id: 'ruy', distance: 120},
    {id: 'let', distance: 90},
    {id: 'rll', distance: 170},
    {id: 'brr', distance: 210},
]


items.push(itemToInsert);

items.sort((itemA, itemB) => {
  if (itemA.distance > itemB.distance) {
    return -1;
  } else if (itemA.distance < itemB.distance) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
})

console.log(items);
```

Comment: What if I want to find if the item to be inserted is in-between ... like 50 <= 100 < =150

Comment: @mex you'd just run the conditional inside the for loop; I'm checking the current datum, but you can check anything there